# Visual studio code python language server is downloaded every time?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-language-server

Every time I open a python file in `visual studio code` after system reboot or shutdown it downloads the language server which is roughly `30 MB`, so I'm asking if there is a way to make it do the download only once?

I'm running **visual studio code 1.35.1** on an **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The language server is downloaded after each upgrade of the Python extension for VS Code and when the language server receives an independent update.

If you don't want to download any file, you can switch to Jedi with the setting `"python.jediEnabled": true`.

Comment: I turned on my system (2019/07/27 00:02 utc+4:30) after a day of being off, my python language server version is 2019.6.24221 which as of the extension info is for 9th of July, But after I started atom it downloaded the language server again which contradicts what you said in your answer.

Comment: I fixed my answer.

Comment: To add this (on ubuntu) from File > Preference > Settings, search `jediEnabled` and check mark it as true (if it is already checked, uncheck it and check again) it will ask you to reload the VSCode, accept it.